# Is it safe to commit .provisionprofile files to public source?

Tags: macos, app-store, provisioning-profile

I am using a CI tool to build our Mac App Store apps. The CI build needs my `Development.provisionprofile` and `Distribution.provisionprofile` to properly build the apps. I can simply commit these profiles to our public GitHub repo and they will be available to the CI tool.

Is it safe to commit development and distribution `.provisionprofile` files to public source? Do they contain any sensitive information? Can they be used maliciously?